# creating javascript objects with unique names depending on counter in loop

Tags: javascript, variables, object, loops

I'm new enough to Javascript, and I have a small query about formulating variable names :

```
function createObjects(int length) {
  var count;
  for(count=0; count<length; count++;) {
    var personObj + "" + count;
  }  
}
```

here I want to formulate a different personObj for each iteration of the for loop, is this the correct procedure? will this give me : 
var personObj1
var personObj2
etc

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: what do you plan to do with these objects after the loop? store them? where?

Comment: You cant do this,you will have to create an array and store the variables in them. Just curious, you are new to javascript want to know if any other language allows me to create variables this way.

Comment: I wanted to create properties for each object and then store them in an array, should i define the properties for one object and then slot each one into an index in an array and then reinitialise the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have several instances of the same underlying data structure / logic you could use an approach like this:

Create a **[constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)** that generates an `Object` with the properties (also methods) that you need. For example:

```
function PersonObj(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

This enables you to create a new instance of `PersonObj` by using `var n = new PersonObj('Fred',32);`. Now you can use an **[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)** to store multiple instancesof these objects:

```
var persons = []; // creates a new Array

for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++){
    persons.push(new PersonObj('Alfred', i));
}
```

`persons` will now contain twelve Alfreds of age 1 to 12.

If you want to alter Alfred No. 3's age you could do:

```
persons[2].age = 99;
```

See **[a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HVFtt/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Dynamically generating variables is never a good idea. Use an object or an array instead. They are designed to structure groups of related data.

```
function createObjects(length) {
  var count, people = [];
  for(count=0; count<length; count++;) {
    people.push('something');
  }  
  return people;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array for this instead?

Answer (score 0):

if needs must, you can alwvays add a named property to the window object:

```
function createObjects(int length) {
  var count;
  for(count=0; count<length; count++;) {
    window[personObj + "" + count] = new SomeObject();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the objects, add properties to objects and store the objects in an array.

```
var al = new Array();
function createObjects(int length) {
 var o = new Object();
  for(var count=0; count<length; count++;) {
      o.count = 'some value';
  } 
al.push(o);
}
```